# Why i cant make yellow bright

Tags: materials, node-editor

I have my mesh and its pale yellow i want to make much bright yellow. In the nodes its bright yellow but render it looks pale yellow. What extra nodes should i add to get a bright yellow. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[image]

**Nodes :**

[image]

**Pale yellow**

[image]

**Need this type of bright yellow**

[image]

Comment: Brighter lights will certainly help. Also, have you increased your light path volume bounces from default low value?

Comment: @RichSedman can you plz make it more clear which node i have to increase etc

Comment: It isn’t a node, it’s the Light Paths properties panel in the Render settings (far right-hand properties pane in the default screen layout). In the Bounces column is a Volume setting - defaults to zero - increase it to 3 or 4 to allow the scatter chance to bounce back out of the volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have the Layer Weight node ("TransFresnel") but my understanding is that the Layer Weight does not have any practical use when used for volumetrics - it should only be used for Surface shaders. In addition, using different densities for the Scatter and Absorption can cause unpredictable (and non-real-world) effects - and typically the Scatter and Absorption shaders should use the *same colour* or, again, this can cause unexpected results. Therefore, I'd suggest the following material :

[image: suggested alternate material]

Note how the RGB node feeds into both volumetric shaders so that the same colour is used for each. This is in place of the Layer Weight node in your set up. Also note the use of a single Value node to control both densities so that the shaders are consistent with each other.

Note also the Volume Bounces at the right-hand side of the image. This defaults to zero which would mean that rays are not permitted to bounce multiple times within the volume as they scatter, causing the light to never reach the camera (making it darker). You should increase the number of bounces to, say, 3 or 4 and this should make the material absorb less light.

The above example was based on the default cube with the only changes the material, brightening the default lamp from 100 to 1000, and increasing the Volume Bounces to 4 and reduced Volume Sampling Step Size from 0.1 to 0.025 to increase the volumetric quality.

Comment: This is the Final result https://imgur.com/gallery/T6d9CEy